# MySQL Multiplied query result (LEFT JOIN, SUM, COUNT, GROUP BY)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to get a simple SUM and COUNT from a table that takes a couple of joins and some math. I can't get it right.

I have 4 tables:

```
USERS
user_id, name
1, user1
2, user2
3, user3
4, user4

RESULTS
user_id, plus, minus
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 0
1, 1, 0
3, 0, 1
3, 1, 0
3, 1, 0
3, 1, 0

NOTES
user_id, note
1, lorem ipsum
3, abc
1, qwerty
3, qwerty

MESSAGES
user_id, message
1, lorem ipsum
3, abc
1, qwerty
3, qwerty
3, qwerty
3, qwerty
3, qwerty
```

I would like to sum all the result of subtracting plus from the minus, amount of notes and amount of messages of users.

My query:

```
SELECT u.`user_id`, SUM(w.`plus`-w.`minus`), COUNT(g.`user_id`), COUNT(m.`user_id`)
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `results` w ON u.`user_id` = w.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `notes` g ON u.`user_id` = g.`user_id` 
LEFT JOIN `messages` m ON u.`user_id` = m.`user_id` 
GROUP BY 1
```

Expected result should looks like:

```
user_id: sum(plus-minus) amount of notes, amount of messages
1: 3, 2, 2
3: 2, 2, 5
```

unfortunatelly query returns:

```
user_id: sum(plus-minus) amount of notes, amount of messages
1: 12, 12, 12
3: 20, 40, 40
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should manually count the records in a subquery for every `user_id` so you will get correct value.

```
SELECT  u.user_ID, u.Name,
        COALESCE(r.totalResult, 0) totalResult,
        COALESCE(n.totalNotes, 0) totalNotes,
        COALESCE(m.totalMessages, 0) totalMessages
FROM    users u 
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, SUM(plus - minus) totalResult
            FROM    Results
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) r ON  u.user_ID = r.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, COUNT(*) totalNotes
            FROM    Notes
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) n ON u.user_ID = n.user_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  user_ID, COUNT(*) totalMessages
            FROM    Messages
            GROUP   BY user_ID
        ) m ON u.user_ID = m.user_ID
```

But if you have set an `auto_incremented` column in every table, the subquery isn't needed since you can distinctly count from it.

Comment: Hiya John, great answer. upvoting and deleting mine. I really need to read much more carefully.

Comment: One thing to be aware of with these kinds of queries is the performance factor. On small datasets with good indexes this is fine - but as your dataset grows this becomes much, much slower - as MySQL does a new query for every single record.

Sometimes you just -have- to use this approach, but that's also why you have tools like denormalization at your disposal ;)